# Anyway to dynamically change GIS layer fill color in Anylogic during runtime?

Tags: simulation, anylogic, dynamics-al

I am building out a transit model with different routes. I would like to be able to shift which route is being displayed during runtime. I have shapefiles for all 3 routes. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Open to other approaches as well?

I tried programmatically accessing the GIS layers and updating the fill color but it appears those properties are not exposed properly for modification.

Comment: GIS layers, you mean shapefiles? Yeah they are not accessible to make changes... you can ask anylogic directly sometimes they have hidden functions.